# The import javax.servlet can't be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to use **eclipse** for **Java EE** to develop web applications.

I need to use **Tomcat** as my **server**. I've downloaded Tomcat and it's running. But my program doesn't compile.

I get the following error:

> The import javax.servlet can't be resolved.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 248, accepted):

You need to add the Servlet API to your classpath. In Tomcat 6.0, this is in a JAR called `servlet-api.jar` in Tomcat's `lib` folder. You can either add a reference to that JAR to the project's classpath, or put a copy of the JAR in your Eclipse project and add it to the classpath from there.

If you want to leave the JAR in Tomcat's `lib` folder:

- Right-click the project, click **Properties**.
- Choose **Java Build Path**.
- Click the **Libraries** tab
- Click **Add External JARs...**
- Browse to find `servlet-api.jar` and select it.
- Click **OK** to update the build path.

Or, if you copy the JAR into your project:

- Right-click the project, click **Properties**.
- Choose **Java Build Path**.
- Click **Add JARs...**
- Find `servlet-api.jar` in your project and select it.
- Click **OK** to update the build path.

Comment: Having a copy of a servletcontainer-specific JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` would make your application unportable. It will only be able to run on the exact same server make/version and not on other server make/versions. `NoClassDefFoundError` would flying around your head.

Comment: I never said it should in in `WEB-INF/lib` - just that it could be copied into the project so that it can be added to the build path. That doesn't necessarily mean it gets included in the WAR.

Comment: Still then, that's plain clumsy and not the recommended approach.

Comment: It is workaround solution. The exact solution is given by BalusC below.

Comment: nothing changed adding servlet-api.jar,
**project** > **clean** made it work.

Comment: Moved Apache tomcat directory after creating a New project, just creating new project in new project workspace with new tomcat server directory worked easily.

Comment: Running a Struts 1.x project on WebLogic 9 cannot resolve `import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` in `ActionForm`. After added `servlet-api.jar` into build path, the error goes away. Thanks.

Comment: Adding the external servlet api worked for me

Answer (score 108):

If not done yet, you need to integrate Tomcat in your *Servers* view. Rightclick there and choose *New > Server*. Select the appropriate Tomcat version from the list and complete the wizard.

When you create a new *Dynamic Web Project*, you should select the integrated server from the list as *Targeted Runtime* in the 1st wizard step.

Or when you have an existing *Dynamic Web Project*, you can set/change it in *Targeted Runtimes* entry in project's properties. Eclipse will then automagically add all its libraries to the build path (without having a copy of them in the project!).

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I have everything as you said, but still it can't resolve javax.servlet (using Tomcat 8.0.3 as server)

Answer (score 20):

You need to set the scope of the dependency to 'provided' in your POM.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

```
<dependency>  
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then everything will be fine.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem because my "Dynamic Web Project" had no reference to the installed server i wanted to use and therefore had no reference to the Servlet API the server provides.

Following steps solved it without adding an extra Servlet-API to the Java Build Path (**Eclipse version: Luna**):

- **Right click** on your "Dynamic Web Project"
- Select **Properties**
- Select **Project Facets** in the list on the left side of the "Properties" wizard
- On the right side of the wizard you should see a tab named **Runtimes**. Select the Runtime tab and **check the server** you want to run the servlet.

**Edit:** if there is no server listed you can create a new one on the Runtimes tab

Answer (score 16):

Add to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Just note that in-case this issue still happen when using maven then we only need to re-build the project again to let it recognize the change from the dependencies.

Answer (score 14):

Add the `servlet-api.jar` to your classpath. You can take it from tomcat's lib folder.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem in Eclipse.  For some reason I didn't have the servlet.jar file in my build path.  What I wound up doing was copying a "lib" folder from another project of mine to the project I was working on, then manually going into that folder and adding the servlet.jar file to the build path (option shows up when you right-click on the file in the project explorer).