# what I need to do to use the ManagedBean library?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsf, servlets

Ive been using anotation for my beans (I havent used them before) and I found out I have to include some dependencies and so on, like this:

```
 <!--JSF API-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PrimeFaces -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Javax Servlet. This needs to be included for runtime only! -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and well.. the problem is that the I keep getting the error of

> The import javax.faces cannot be resolved

Every time I need to use the managed bean... I am using Maven and I am supposed to have downloaded all things I need, I also tried other POM and in that project I can use anotations, so, I guess is a misconfiguratino of the POM? I didnt do anything special to ecplise, except enable the `maven clean, maven eclipse, and maven eclipse skip test`

I really checked other answers, like these:

[The import javax.servlet can't be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119448/the-import-javax-servlet-cant-be-resolved)
[How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

but nothing, any idea what could be wrong??

Comment: What version of maven and eclipse are you using? And what are you using for a servet container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer, I checked that using Maven its a little bit different and in the built path you have to specify the path for your maven repository, so, it will incluide all libraries directly or you can copy and past them into your project

Answer (score 1):

You should not import the servlet API but implementation of the API, for example the servlet container implementation you want on which you want to run your project : Tomcat, JBoss, Websphere, Glassfish....
E.g. for tomcat :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.30</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```