# Maven messed up build path

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

I was adding maven dependencies to my web application, and when I ran maven > update project, the build path got messed up. It switched my JRE system Library to one that doesn't exist. I ended up fixing that, but still can't get the project to compile.

I'm using java SE 1.7. Using eclipse for java EE developers, with the maven plugin. The Servlet and JSP support should come from the Tomcat server. How can I get this working again?

Please help, this is my senior project and it is due in two days :(

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found another question that answers mine, maybe someone will come here and find this useful.

The fix was to re-add the apache server to the targeted runtime of the project. Here's the original: [The import javax.servlet can't be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119448/the-import-javax-servlet-cant-be-resolved) solved by BalusC.

Also changed the version inside the pom.xml to the correct one. The 1.8 should match jdk version.

```
<configuration>
  <source>1.8</source>
  <target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
```