# Import javax.servlet not working in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, ubuntu-18.04

I know its duplicate, and before everyone give link to the solved question, [I have already tried the steps here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119448/the-import-javax-servlet-cant-be-resolved)
and I'm still facing the issue on every project I'm creating, [these are the error shown when I create Servlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TQJ8.png)
even though all files are shown and are included in [build path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8NaF.png) and the server is also recognised by the [eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yShqy.png) its still not linking the API to the project

Answer (score 0):

I was using the servlet-api given by tomcat and they have placed all the classes in
`jakarta.servlet.*;`
so when creating servlet from eclipse, it doesn't know the change and created the file with `javax.servlet.*;`, the universal way, and had to import again from jakarta package.
which caused the issue.